# How can I model a cylindrical bottle lid base with unusual upper shape (arm extending to cap)?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

somewhat new to Blender and have a quick question about modeling an object I can't find in any tutorials. I am trying to practice modeling for product development and want to create this lid in Blender. Because the base is a cylinder, i'm having trouble modeling the top part of the lid.

I've had some experience modeling complex shapes with cubes/rectangular prisms but haven't encountered a situation where I'm using a cylinder.

Specifically, creating the slanted surface above the cylinder as well as the spout where water comes out is challenging for me, because the face of the cylinder is not easy to model with.

Any advice or links to tutorials that might be helpful would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Full water bottle]

[image: Water bottle lid]

[image: Water bottle lid 2]

Comment: You can't really see the detail or even the bigger forms in the image. It would help you a lot to get better reference. If you cannot tell what the form is precisely, you certainly will not be able to model it precisely. This looks like a lot of guessing. Also the question seems a bit broad. You should narrow it down to a more specific part that you struggle with. At the moment it would probably require at least half an hour video tutorial to answer in detail - how do you expect anyone to fit that into a text answer?..

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys apologies for the lack of clarification and low quality reference image files, I'm a bit new to this. I've added a couple better reference pictures and tried to be a bit more specific. The bottom half of the bottle is clearly rather simple, as it's just a cylinder, but the top half, specifically where the spout comes out of the lid, is challenging me. I am having trouble modeling with the cylinder cap, and not sure how I should proceed.

Comment: :D Oh my... You had that?! And did not share it?! Are you joking? :D

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys apologies - didnt realize it was unclear

Comment: Well, you sure messed up things for the next guy, because I will surely not be answering questions like that again any time soon... :D

Comment: I think this is part of the struggle though - you don't realise just how important it is to see and understand the form you are trying to model and that's part of why it is hard for you.  It is very important to see and understand what it is that you are supposed to model.

Comment: that's what i'm realizing. sorry for the poor question and will definitely try to focus on looking deeper into all of the reference images to formulate a better shape in my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tubes and cylinders are probably easier, the organic shape is a bit trickier. When you have insufficient, bad quality reference images, you can start with placing only the edges you can see in the reference, only when you can guess their position in 3d space. Then you have something to work with and can start filling the spaces between them with surfaces constantly adjusting everything as needed when you compare your result to the reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would use F2 add-on for quick filling and LoopTools add-on for relaxing edge loop segments. I would simply keep extruding single vertex to make the lines. Subdividing edges to get a vert in the middle is useful, also using Bevel for vertices(Ctrl + Shift +B) can be a quick way to place multiple vertices in a smooth curve. The idea here is to keep in mind that this geometry is for Subdivision modifier(you could also just add the modifier to see the result while working), you should have as little geometry here, as possible, only enough to hold the forms, because the fewer points you have the easier it is to adjust them. I would use edge creasing(Ctrl + E) and Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth and add resolution to everything then I would bevel the resulting sharp edges with Bevel modifier. It's easy to use edge bevel weight as limit for the modifier because you can set edge weight at the same time you crease the edges.

[image]

That's the reference initially provided:

[image]

Comment: that's super helpful. i'm not familiar with f2 add on yet so I need to go watch some tutorials on it first. - what is the initial method you're using to create vertices and edges rather than working based off of a mesh (like cube, cylinder...) I will go try to familiarize myself with that.

Comment: The add-ons come with Blender, you just need to enable them in the preferences. It's possible to model this without them, but they make things a lot easier and do not require much learning, so I definitely recommend using them.

Comment: I am mostly just extruding vertices, sometimes I may select an edge and subdivide it so I get a vert in the middle, then I can move it and also ctrl+shift+b "bevels" edge connecting vertices.

Comment: Ok got it. I appreciate the help